# Append string to the map type in Terraform

Tags: terraform, hcl, zipmap

I have a next expression in Terraform (v0.11.7):

```
my_expression = "${zipmap(random_shuffle.x.result, random_shuffle.x.result)}"
```

I need to append string to right expression, e.g:

```
my_expression = "${zipmap(random_shuffle.x.result, "*" + random_shuffle.x.result)}"
```

Do I have any solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to achieve this would be as follows:

```
my_expression = "${zipmap(random_shuffle.x.result,formatlist("*%s",random_shuffle.x.result))}"
```